# How to avoid goto VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I read multiple times that GoTo should be avoided in codes, however I regularly have to create loops and if an item gives me an error, the code will stop.

In the below case, I have to compare cell values, but I get an error if I there's string in the cell.

Do you have any other option to avoid the GoTo for the below code?

Thanks!

```
Sub Conditional()

        Dim x As Integer



        For x = 1 To 31



            On Error GoTo na


            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8 + x, 5) >= 0.95 Then

                Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Shape " & x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)

            ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8 + x, 5) < 0.95 Then

                Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Shape " & x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

            End If

            GoTo nextx

na:

            Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Shape " & x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            On Error GoTo -1

nextx:
        Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Proper error trapping / handling might be the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, if you want to check for the string in the cell it is like this:

```
Sub Conditional()

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To 31
        If IsNumeric(Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(8 + x, 5)) Then
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8 + x, 5) >= 0.95 Then

                Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Shape " & x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)

            ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8 + x, 5) < 0.95 Then

                Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Shape " & x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

            End If
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

In general, goto should be used only for error catching, like `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` with no exclustions.

Comment: `IsNumeric()` can fail in some circumstances and return `True` (="it's a number") for something that's not actually a number. For instance `IsNumeric("1..23")` would return `True`. While `SpecialCells(.., xlNumbers)` would return _real_ numbers. See my answer below

Comment: Can you try `?isnumeric(range("A3"))` and tell me what you get when you put `1..23` in the cell?

Comment: it returns `True`

Comment: @user3598756 Can I get a screenshot of that? Pls. That is mine: https://postimg.org/image/aitkcx4e1/

Comment: I'm not able to attach a screenshot nor willing to learn how to by now. You have to take my word. I can add that my `True` example was for a "double dot" _number_ like `1..23` while your screenshits shows a "triple dot" one 2) I tried with a "triple dot" _number_ and still getting `True` 3) I tried with `1,..23` and still getting `True`. 4) Then I tried `1,,23` and got `False`. 5) So it's a matter of local decimal point representation but anyway the issue with `IsNumeric` holds true

Comment: Did you try by submitting the parameter as a range or by giving it like this `IsNumeric("1..23")`? The results are different.

Comment: I did it both ways. Look, the IsNumeric() issue is a well known one: it's all fine as long as you know that your data are either a "honest" string or a "honest" number. But if you have to bother mistypings or the likes then it's not your horse

Comment: Actually you are right, I was referring to a wrong sheet in the screenshot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

since you're doing some formatting depending on cells *type* (`text` or `numbers`) then you could use [SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) method of `Range` object and type a function like follows:

```
Function GetCells(rng As Range, cellType As XlCellType, cellValues As XlSpecialCellsValue, outputRng As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next '<--| ignore subsequent errors, if any
    Set outputRng = rng.SpecialCells(cellType, cellValues) '<--| get a sub-range out of passed range as filtered by passed arguments
    GetCells = Not outputRng Is Nothing '<--| returns 'True' if range has been properly set
End Function
```

and exploit it as follows:

```
Sub Conditional()
    Dim myCells As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet  1").Range("E9:E39") '<--| reference your sheet relevant range        
        If GetCells(.Cells, xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers, myCells) Then '<--| if any cells whose value is a "constant" "number" in your range
            For Each cell In myCells '<--| loop through those filtered cells
                Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Shape " & cell.row - 8).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(cell.Value >= 0.95, RGB(0, 176, 80), RGB(255, 0, 0)) '<--| format your shapes as per corresponding current cell
            Next cell
        End If

        If GetCells(.Cells, xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues, myCells) Then '<--| if any cells whose value is a "constant" "text" in your range
            Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes("Shape " & cell.row - 8).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) '<--| format your shapes as per corresponding current cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```